# Python - How to get tr td after tf was already used

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So, here's my code:

```
link = "https://nookipedia.com/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Insect&cmlimit=500&format=json"
async with aiohttp.get(link) as t:
    result = await t.json()
    foundCheck = False
    for list in result["query"]["categorymembers"]:
        print(list["title"])
        if bug.lower() == list["title"].lower():
            print(bug)
            await self.bot.say("{} is a real bug".format(bug.title()))
            bug2 = bug.replace(" ", "_")
            url = "https://nookipedia.com/wiki/{}".format(bug2)
            await self.bot.say(url)
            async with aiohttp.get(url) as response:
                soupObject = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "html.parser")
                try:
                    info = soupObject.find(id="Infobox-bug").tr.td.get_text()
                    await self.bot.say("{}".format(info))
                except:
                    await self.bot.say("Can't get the content from {}".format(url))
            foundCheck = True
            return
    if not foundCheck:
        await self.bot.say("That bug does not exist")
        return
    else:
        await self.bot.say("Error")
```

and here's the html code i'm trying to get:

```
<table id="Infobox-bug" align="right" style="background: #adff2f; margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-radius: 10px; -icab-border-radius: 10px; -o-border-radius: 10px; border: 3px solid #9acd32; width: 25%">

<tr align="center">
<td colspan="2"> <big><big><b>Pill Bug</b></big></big>
</td></tr>
<tr align="center">
<td style="background: #caecc9; border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-radius: 10px; -icab-border-radius: 10px; -o-border-radius: 10px;" colspan="2"> <a href="/wiki/File:Pill_Bug_Picture.jpg" class="image"><img alt="Pill Bug Picture.jpg" src="/w/images/b/bb/Pill_Bug_Picture.jpg" width="199" height="186" /></a>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d; border-top-left-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 10px; -icab-border-top-left-radius: 10px; -o-border-top-left-radius: 10px;" align="right"> Scientific name
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff; border-top-right-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-top-right-radius: 10px; -icab-border-top-right-radius: 10px; -o-border-top-right-radius: 10px;" align="left"> <i>Armadillidium vulgare</i>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d" align="right"> Family
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff" align="left"> <i>Armadillidiidae - Terrestrial Custaceans</i>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d" align="right"> Time of year
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff" align="left"> All year
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d" align="right"> Time of day
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff" align="left"> All day
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d" align="right"> Location
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff" align="left"> Under rocks
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d" align="right"> Size
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff" align="left"> 2 mm
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d" align="right"> Rarity
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff" align="left"> Common
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d" align="right"> Selling price
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff" align="left"> 250 <a href="/wiki/Bells" title="Bells">Bells</a>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; -icab-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; -o-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;" align="right"> Appearances
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; -icab-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; -o-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;" align="left"> <i><a href="/wiki/Doubutsu_no_Mori_(game)" title="Doubutsu no Mori (game)">Doubutsu no Mori</a></i>,<br /><i><a href="/wiki/Animal_Crossing_(GCN)" title="Animal Crossing (GCN)">Animal Crossing</a></i>,<br /><i><a href="/wiki/Animal_Crossing:_Wild_World" title="Animal Crossing: Wild World">Animal Crossing: Wild World</a></i>,<br /><i><a href="/wiki/Animal_Crossing:_City_Folk" title="Animal Crossing: City Folk">Animal Crossing: City Folk</a></i>,<br /><i><a href="/wiki/Animal_Crossing:_New_Leaf" title="Animal Crossing: New Leaf">Animal Crossing: New Leaf</a></i>
</td></tr></table>
```

So, basically i got the "Pill Bug" (aka `info`) as it own string but i'm not sure how to get everything else after it (within the tr and td) without getting pill bug again? How would i do that so i can get each text as their own strings?

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: `list_of_td = find_all('td')` and later `for td in list_of_td:`

Comment: and does that do exactly? @furas and how would i get the first, second, third one

Comment: use `for td in list_of_td` to get one by one - or `list_of_td[0]`, `list_of_td[1]`, etc. if you need only some of them.

Comment: `soupObejct. find_all('td')` finds all `td` tags and returns as list. You can also do `table = soupObject.find(id="Infobox-bug")` and later `table.find_all('td')` to find all `td` only in this `table`. More in BeautifulSoup documentation.

Comment: i tried this but it's not return nothing http://prntscr.com/di8cz8

Comment: I tried only this http://pastebin.com/dqJ2iG14 and it works for me. Results at the end of script.

Comment: That works like a charm

Comment: Just gonna ask to more thing, how would i get the `th` and how would i get the src file from the `tds[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BS` has many methods to get tags and it parameters

- `soup.find(args)`
- `soup.find_all(args)`
- `soup.select(CSS_selection)`
- `tag.get(param)` or `tag.get(param, default)` or `tag[param]`
- `tag.text` or `tag.get_text()`
- `tag.name`
- etc.

And `find()` / `find_all()` may use different arguments - so you have to read [BS doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for more.

Example:

```
html = '''<table id="Infobox-bug" align="right" style="background: #adff2f; margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-radius: 10px; -icab-border-radius: 10px; -o-border-radius: 10px; border: 3px solid #9acd32; width: 25%">

<tr align="center">
<td colspan="2"> <big><big><b>Pill Bug</b></big></big>
</td></tr>
<tr align="center">
<td style="background: #caecc9; border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-radius: 10px; -icab-border-radius: 10px; -o-border-radius: 10px;" colspan="2"> <a href="/wiki/File:Pill_Bug_Picture.jpg" class="image"><img alt="Pill Bug Picture.jpg" src="/w/images/b/bb/Pill_Bug_Picture.jpg" width="199" height="186" /></a>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d; border-top-left-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 10px; -icab-border-top-left-radius: 10px; -o-border-top-left-radius: 10px;" align="right"> Scientific name
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff; border-top-right-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-top-right-radius: 10px; -icab-border-top-right-radius: 10px; -o-border-top-right-radius: 10px;" align="left"> <i>Armadillidium vulgare</i>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d" align="right"> Family
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff" align="left"> <i>Armadillidiidae - Terrestrial Custaceans</i>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d" align="right"> Time of year
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff" align="left"> All year
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d" align="right"> Time of day
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff" align="left"> All day
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d" align="right"> Location
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff" align="left"> Under rocks
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d" align="right"> Size
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff" align="left"> 2 mm
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d" align="right"> Rarity
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff" align="left"> Common
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d" align="right"> Selling price
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff" align="left"> 250 <a href="/wiki/Bells" title="Bells">Bells</a>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #86df2d; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; -icab-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; -o-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;" align="right"> Appearances
</th>
<td style="background:#ffffff; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; -icab-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; -o-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;" align="left"> <i><a href="/wiki/Doubutsu_no_Mori_(game)" title="Doubutsu no Mori (game)">Doubutsu no Mori</a></i>,<br /><i><a href="/wiki/Animal_Crossing_(GCN)" title="Animal Crossing (GCN)">Animal Crossing</a></i>,<br /><i><a href="/wiki/Animal_Crossing:_Wild_World" title="Animal Crossing: Wild World">Animal Crossing: Wild World</a></i>,<br /><i><a href="/wiki/Animal_Crossing:_City_Folk" title="Animal Crossing: City Folk">Animal Crossing: City Folk</a></i>,<br /><i><a href="/wiki/Animal_Crossing:_New_Leaf" title="Animal Crossing: New Leaf">Animal Crossing: New Leaf</a></i>
</td></tr></table>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#import requests
#r = requests.get('https://nookipedia.com/wiki/Pill_Bug')
#html = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
tds = soup.find(id="Infobox-bug").find_all('td')

print('--- all td text ---')

for x in tds:
    print('>', x.get_text().strip())
    # or 
    print('>', x.text.strip())

print('--- one td text ---')

print(tds[0].text.strip())

print('--- one td a href ---')

print(tds[1].find('a').get('href'))
# or
print(tds[1].find('a')['href'])

print('--- all a href (using CSS selector) ---')

for a in soup.select('#Infobox-bug td a'):
    print(a['href'])

print('--- all td and th ---')

for tt in soup.find(id='Infobox-bug').find_all({'td', 'th'}):
    if tt.name == 'th':
        print('[', tt.name, ']', tt.text.strip(), end=" --> ")
    elif tt.name == 'td':
        a = tt.find('a')
        if a:
            a = a['href']
        else:
            a = 'None'
        print('[', tt.name, ']', tt.text.strip(), '(', a, ')')
```

Result:

```
--- all td text ---
> Pill Bug
> Pill Bug
> 
> 
> Armadillidium vulgare
> Armadillidium vulgare
> Armadillidiidae - Terrestrial Custaceans
> Armadillidiidae - Terrestrial Custaceans
> All year
> All year
> All day
> All day
> Under rocks
> Under rocks
> 2 mm
> 2 mm
> Common
> Common
> 250 Bells
> 250 Bells
> Doubutsu no Mori,Animal Crossing,Animal Crossing: Wild World,Animal Crossing: City Folk,Animal Crossing: New Leaf
> Doubutsu no Mori,Animal Crossing,Animal Crossing: Wild World,Animal Crossing: City Folk,Animal Crossing: New Leaf

--- one td text ---
Pill Bug

--- one td a href ---
/wiki/File:Pill_Bug_Picture.jpg
/wiki/File:Pill_Bug_Picture.jpg

--- all a href (using CSS selector) ---
/wiki/File:Pill_Bug_Picture.jpg
/wiki/Bells
/wiki/Doubutsu_no_Mori_(game)
/wiki/Animal_Crossing_(GCN)
/wiki/Animal_Crossing:_Wild_World
/wiki/Animal_Crossing:_City_Folk
/wiki/Animal_Crossing:_New_Leaf

--- all td and th ---
[ td ] Pill Bug ( None )
[ td ]  ( /wiki/File:Pill_Bug_Picture.jpg )
[ th ] Scientific name --> [ td ] Armadillidium vulgare ( None )
[ th ] Family --> [ td ] Armadillidiidae - Terrestrial Custaceans ( None )
[ th ] Time of year --> [ td ] All year ( None )
[ th ] Time of day --> [ td ] All day ( None )
[ th ] Location --> [ td ] Under rocks ( None )
[ th ] Size --> [ td ] 2 mm ( None )
[ th ] Rarity --> [ td ] Common ( None )
[ th ] Selling price --> [ td ] 250 Bells ( /wiki/Bells )
[ th ] Appearances --> [ td ] Doubutsu no Mori,Animal Crossing,Animal Crossing: Wild World,Animal Crossing: City Folk,Animal Crossing: New Leaf ( /wiki/Doubutsu_no_Mori_(game) )
```